# Form Field is not shown and it can be accessible before just by pressing submit button

Tags: python, django

I still try to learn Django.I just want to make my form field stay continuously in my template but when ı try, it just can be accessible in my template after by push the submit button. How can ı fix this problem.I have not found any answer yet.
At first as you can see in my views.py ı tried to do return render method for either form valid or not but not worked for me

views.py

```
class ItemDetailView(FormMixin,DetailView):
 model=Item
 template_name='product-page.html'
 form_class= CO


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        qs=Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user,ordered=False)
        context['count'] = qs[0]
    
    return context


def get_success_url(self):
    
    return reverse("shopping:product", kwargs={"slug": self.object.slug})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    self.object = self.get_object()
    
    form = self.get_form()
    
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
  
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
    return render_to_response(request,'product-page.html',{'form':form})

def form_valid(self,form):
        number=form.cleaned_data['qualt']
         # create item in order_item which come from get_object_or_404
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        
        order_item, created= OrderedItem.objects.get_or_create(ıtem=item,user=self.request.user,ordered=False) # create item in order_item which come from get_object_or_404
        order_qs= Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user,ordered=False)
               
         # there is  any user  who haven't had order yet 
        if order_qs.exists(): # Is there any user who haven't had order yet 
            order= order_qs[0]
            if order.ıtems.filter(ıtem__slug=item.slug).exists():
                
                order_item.quantity += number
                order_item.save()
                messages.success(self.request, f'Item added to your cart ({order_item.quantity}) {item.title} in Cart ')
            else:
                order.ıtems.add(order_item)
                order_item.quantity += number-1
                order_item.save()
                messages.success(self.request, f'Item added to your cart .Now you Have Already ({order_item.quantity}) {item.title} in Cart ')
        else:
            ordered_date=timezone.now()
            order=Order.objects.create(user=self.request.user,ordered_date=ordered_date)
            order.ıtems.add(order_item)
            order_item.quantity += number
            order_item.save()   
            messages.success(self.request, f'Item added to your cart . ({order_item.quantity}) {item.title} in Cart ')
```

forms.py

```
  from django import forms

  class CO(forms.Form):
   qualt=forms.IntegerField(min_value=1,required=True,label="qualt")
```

template html:

```
   <form method="POST" action="" class="d-flex justify-content-left">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form|crispy}}
         <div class="container">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md " type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you call `super` method of `DetailView`. it doesn't provide form to your context. change it to `super(ItemDetailView, self).get_context_data` or `super().get_context_data`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ItemDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        qs=Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user,ordered=False)
        context['count'] = qs[0]
    
    return context
```

Comment: Thanks a lot thats work for me ,the weird things that other additional context had already been worked before I changed .

Comment: and some more actions. you use context['count'] = qs[0], it will throw an exception if there is no items in Order model. Replace it with qs.first(). if will return None if there is no items